# How do I control the normalization of bars heights in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, reporting, normalization, jfreechart, bar-chart

Suppose I want to present 2 charts in one context (page) so a user can examine both charts and compare them by their appearance. I would also like my user to notice trend differences, as well as  absolute values differences.
As seen in the attached figure, in case both charts have the same trend, JFreeChart rendering mechanism normalizes them, so both of them look just the same!!! (although there is a huge absolute values difference between) 
I would like to control the normalization mechanism of the BarRenderer and avoid this behaviour.
Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any option to do automatically what you want, but here's a solution: 
you disable the autorange of each axis with the [setAutoRange](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setAutoRange%28boolean%29) method (the axes are retrieved via `XYPlot.getRangeAxis()`), and next manually set the same bounds on the axis with [setRange](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setRange%28double,%20double%29) and [setTickUnit](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setTickUnit%28org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit%29). This implies that you "guess" yourself the best max for your chart.